# How to view image using google docs?

Tags: html, google-docs

I am tried to show an image using google docs. But it does not work for image. But it perfectly work for pdf and doc files.

My code is given below.

```
<iframe id="iframe_certificate" class="iframe_show"  src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://fireandsafetyforum.net/LMS/director/images/test.jpg&amp;embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Docs' doesn't host (its an editing program), Google Drive does (its storage).

There are two requirements to publish content from Google Drive:
1. the folder is made public;
2. a webViewLink URL is created for the content.

See: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/publish-site

Your source doesn't look like the URL example given. It looks like it might be a rendering of the relevant file (not the file) in Google Docs.

If you haven't done so, I suggest you use above page to make sure the relevant file is made public and given a proper URL.